# GitLab CI stuck at "Waiting Fargate task to be ready" - but Fargate task is in fact running, but never completes

Tags: gitlab-ci, aws-fargate

Having set up GitLab CI and AWS Fargate resources as described in [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws_fargate/), we have a situation where the runner can trigger the Fargate task, which goes into RUNNING state, but the master runner never seems to realize this.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.7.0 (98daeee0)
  on gitlab-fargate-master DyE5BsVA
Preparing the "custom" executor
INFO[2022-01-27T13:54:49Z] Starting fargate                              PID=1447 version="0.2.0 (933d940)"
INFO[2022-01-27T13:54:49Z] Executing the command                         PID=1447 command=config_exec
Using Custom executor with driver fargate 0.2.0 (933d940)...
INFO[2022-01-27T13:54:49Z] Starting fargate                              PID=1452 version="0.2.0 (933d940)"
INFO[2022-01-27T13:54:49Z] Executing the command                         PID=1452 command=prepare_exec
INFO[2022-01-27T13:54:56Z] Starting new Fargate task                     PID=1452 command=prepare_exec
INFO[2022-01-27T13:54:58Z] Persisting data that will be used by other commands  PID=1452 command=prepare_exec taskARN="arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:558517226390:task/gitlab-ci-cluster/ee488fa1d7d7475fab9be01d5bad180e"
INFO[2022-01-27T13:54:58Z] Waiting Fargate task to be ready              PID=1452 command=prepare_exec taskARN="arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:558517226390:task/gitlab-ci-cluster/ee488fa1d7d7475fab9be01d5bad180e"
```

Within AWS, the task has created its Log Stream in Cloudwatch, but there are no events in that log. It's unclear what is actually happening.

What can be done to find out?

We have reverted to using a vanilla Docker container from the GitLab documentation `registry.gitlab.com/tmaczukin-test-projects/fargate-driver-debian:latest` but exactly same happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved - problem was missing AWS permission ECS:DescribeTasks, which for some reason was not causing an error message in the Runner.

(I had mistakenly added AmazonEC2_FullAccess, not AmazonECS_FullAccess as described in [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws_fargate/))

Having run a "Generate Policy" in AWS based on CloudTrail Events (awesome new feature!), I can now confirm the permissions actually being used are:

EC2: DescribeNetworkInterfaces.
ECS: StopTask, DescribeTasks, RunTask

Note the EC2 permission, which is missing from the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have solved your problem but I noticed this question as I had the exact same issue yesterday. For me this was caused as my gitlab manager task was using an IAM role which was limited to start and stop tasks but it was apparently missing permissions to check weather a task is in the RUNNING state. So I fixed my ecs execution role and then it started working for me.

Comment: Same here. Will post an answer with details.